# Is WebService can work's parallel or only columnar?

Tags: c#, web-services

Do calls to webservice from multiple clients execute in parallel or one by one (i.e. will the 2nd call be considered only after 1st call is complete)?

thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gold: Has my editing helped to frame the question, you want to ask?

Comment: Parallel. They work in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Calls to web services are essentially calls to web pages on a server. The server typically maintains a thread pool from which it retrieves threads to serve incoming calls. So if a number of computers call the same web service method at the same time, they will be executed in parallell as long as there are threads available in the thread pool. If all threads are already busy method calls will start to be put on hold (and the server may even report that it is too busy to handle the request). 5 computers should not pose a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

A web service can respond to a request.  So, what you'll need to do is have a function that all 5 computers call to submit the data you need from each machine.  Then, create a function that each computer calls to check if the response is ready.  Once the data from each computer is collected, the web service would respond with the correct data.

Web service responses must be initiated by the client, not the server.

For example,

1. `SubmitData(data)` returns bool -> each computer submits data, returns if successful or not.  The server stores the responses in a DB.
2. `GetResponse()` returns data or FALSE -> The server checks if all 5 computers have responded.  If not, return FALSE.  If true, process and return the data.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all web services frameworks supports a-synchronicity.
if you are using C#, then you might benifit from the following article:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/security/article.php/c9179